# binding bean property with multiple objects in struts

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts-1

Is this possible to bind a **strut-1** Bean property to multiple form elements?for example, i am dynamically creating rows and each row has a drop down, can i bind all those drop downs with single Bean property (something like values in array) so i can fetch the values of all drop downs easily.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Name all your select boxes the same way (`foos`, for example), and have a method

```
public void setFoos(String[] foos) {
    ...
}
```

in your form bean.

Comment: so my property will be `private String[] checkbox;` ??

Comment: Yes, for example. The setter does whatever it wants. It could store the foos in an array, or in a list, or anything. That's what encapsulation is all about.

Comment: but i am still a little confused about setter. on submission will it be called with the array of Strings having status of each drop down?

Comment: Yes. That's what you asked isn't it?